# Using Session Scope with Spring Batch?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-batch

I'm working on a prototype that initiates Spring Batch jobs from web requests. The jobs consist of a series of Tasklets, and I'd like the Tasklets to have some of their members auto-wired in with a session scope.

I'd also like to be able to use the role of the user who initiated the request in Spring Security if possible.

Is there a sensible way to do this?

Comment: Don't use session scope, pass the needed things as parameters and use step scope. You could create a launcher that uses the roles or just store them in the execution context and use an listener to set them before launching the job.

Comment: We were thinking of using Job scope rather than Step scope. But would ideally like to not have to pass them in...

Comment: You don't want to tie your batch jobs to the web which is what you do when using session or request scopes. Keep them clean makes it also a whole lot easier to test.

Comment: Ok thanks, we'll look into doing it by passing them in then.